# How to increment with hash rocket?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I increment here? Instead of +1 it only shows '1'

```
\App\Coupon::where('coupon_id','=',$coupon[0]->coupon_id)->update(['no_applied' => 'no_applied'+1]);
```

Comment: Do you want to append `1` instead of adding it?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber increment is alright but can you teach me how to append? I want to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use justr `increment` method:

```
App\Coupon::where('coupon_id','=',$coupon[0]->coupon_id)->increment('no_applied');
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I will mark your answer later because stackoverflow won't allow me. Can't accept an answer for 10mins